# In a Setup Project is it possible to validate the user input in a TextBox(A) dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, custom-action

I am using the VS 2010 to create a setup project, I am going to use the TextBox(A) dialog to capture user input.

I would also like to validate inputted value in these text box. Something likes the Next button just be enabled only when the first text box meets a specific criteria. So that, the installer just navigates user to next page when the validation passed.

Is it possible with the VS 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no support in VS setups for doing this. It's a feature that's available in other tools and is part of Windows Installer, so you'd need to use another tool to add that functionality to the setup.

Answer (score 0):

I know its not the exact you need but it will gives you idea on how to parse the value during install. See  the following link [**in Scott Guru Blog**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-creating-packaged-asp-net-setup-programs-with-vs-2005)

and post the solution if you find because for that sake i am now developing a click once application.