# Creating an Installer with a custom Dialog window that validates user input

Tags: c#, installation, wix, setup-project

So I need to create an installer for a .NET project I'm working on with a custom window for a license validation and activation. This means that I would need to validate some user input (I need a valid License Key) to activate the license before proceeding with the instalation. I've tried multiple approaches but so far nothing is working. Here's what I tried:

1. Using the Microsoft Setup Project for Visual Studio, I tried calling a WPF window during the instalation process. However, the window just does not show up, as I've explained in my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73800004/displaying-a-wpf-window-from-an-installer-class?noredirect=1#comment130322428_73800004). So far, I've found no workaround for this.
2. Still using the Microsoft Setup Project for VS, I can add custom dialogs to the installer but it is apparently not possible (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098329/in-a-setup-project-is-it-possible-to-validate-the-user-input-in-a-textboxa-dia) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179609/how-do-you-get-an-installer-to-pause-allow-validation)) to validate user input of this dialog before continuing with the instalation process.
3. I've also tried implementing a WiX installer but I cannot access the WiX Editors and it seems that [Add-In Express's Designer for WiX Toolset](https://www.add-in-express.com/wix-designer/index.php) has been discontinued. Would what I need even be possible to implement if I had access to the editors?

How should I do this? I would be thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: [I prefer to put license validation in the application for many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24360658/129130). Please skim. However, it is certainly technically possible to do this in the setup - I have done so myself (enough to conclude that you should put this in the application you install - if possible). Installshield and Advanced Installer have ready-made dialogs for this purpose, and WiX can certainly to it, however I don't have a sample ready for you I am afraid.

Comment: These samples relate to WiX GUI, but they don't deal with licensing: https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXCustomDialog, https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXOpenLogFile, https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXViewLogExperiment - and [an old answer on WiX / MSI GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654935/changing-text-color-to-wix-dialogs/52674815#52674815).

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to set a new UPGRADEGUID in some of these samples to make them compile. You will see the field say "PUT-GUID-HERE" or similar.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Thank you for your answers! I will check the documentation you provided and reconsider putting license validation in the application, instead of the setup.

Comment: Hope the samples help. Please test what works for your purpose. More links on my experimental site: https://www.installdude.com/jumpgate.php. The [answer with rationales for validation put in the application instead of the setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24360658/129130) could help managers accept the change?